Flutter Build Console showing this - Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken
I am encountering an error in the console while creating the APK.
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 3336 bytes (99.8% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          839.5s
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (71.3MB)

Using the latest Flutter version- 3.24.3
Please suggest ways to resolve this issue.

Try this command: flutter build apk --no-tree-shake-icons

Try put this line in your pubspec.yaml file
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true # Remove or comment out this line to exclude Material Icons

Please review this question like you issue

After comment out showing this-
Expected to find fonts for (MaterialIcons), but found (). This usually means you are referring to font families in an IconData class but not including them in the assets section of your pubspec.yaml, are missing the package that would include them, or are missing "uses-material-design: true".
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

You can try add this : flutter:   fonts:     - family: MaterialIcons       fonts:         - asset: fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf 
